# Enqueue/Dequeue/Insert struct in a queue

Tags: c, struct, queue

I have a struct that contains pointer `next`. I am trying to make a queue of the structs, but when I call `enqueue/dequeue` I eventually get errors trying to write information; and don't know if it's due to `enque/dequeue/insert`. Just learning C and not really sure of `free/malloc` or if they're necessary. Insert is based on int value (smallest value first).

```
struct queue { 
    struct RCB* front; 
    struct RCB* back; 
};

/*Initialize queue */ 
struct queue* new_queue(void){
    struct queue* tmp = malloc( 1 * sizeof(tmp));  
    tmp->front = NULL; 
    tmp->back = NULL;
    return tmp;  
}

/*Add RCB to Queue FIFO */
struct queue* enqueue(struct queue* queue, struct RCB* rcb){
    if(queue->front == NULL && queue->back == NULL){
        queue->front = rcb; 
        queue->back = rcb;
            printf("added front to queue\n");  
        return queue; 
    }
    else {
        queue->back->next = rcb; 
        queue->back = rcb;
            printf("added to queue\n");  
    }
    return queue; 
} 

/*Remove RCB from Queue FIFO */ 
struct RCB* dequeue(struct queue* queue){
    struct RCB *tmp1 = (struct RCB *)malloc(sizeof(struct RCB)); 
    struct RCB *tmp2 = (struct RCB *)malloc(sizeof(struct RCB)); 
    if(queue->front == NULL && queue->back == NULL){
        printf("queue is empty\n"); 
    }   
    tmp1 = queue->front; 
    tmp2 = tmp1->next; 
    queue->front = tmp2; 
    if(queue->front == NULL){
        queue->back = queue->front;
            printf("removed rcb from queue\n");  
    }
    return tmp1; 
}
/*Insert RCB into Queue */ 
 struct queue* insert(struct queue* queue, struct RCB* rcb){
            if(queue->front == NULL && queue->back == NULL){
                queue->front = rcb; 
                queue->back = rcb;
                return queue; 
            }
            if(queue->front->next == NULL){
                queue->front->next = rcb; 
                return queue; 
            }

            struct RCB *tmp = (struct RCB *)malloc(sizeof(struct RCB));
                    tmp = queue->front; 
                        while(tmp->next->b2r < rcb->b2r || tmp->next == NULL){
                        tmp = tmp->next;
                    }
                    rcb->next = tmp->next; 
                    tmp->next = rcb; 

                    return queue; 
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `sizeof(tmp)` is wrong, it's the size of the *pointer* and not what it points to. You should use `sizeof(*tmp)` instead.

Comment: thanks !, still learning about pointers

Comment: The two `malloc` in `dequeue` got leaked, remove them, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [Do not cast `malloc` return value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/436559)
2. in `new_queue`, `struct queue* tmp = malloc( 1 * sizeof(tmp));` is wrong since this will allocate a buffer with size of pointer to `struct queue`, instead of the size of `struct queue`, also the `1*foo` thing is not useful at all. Use following:

   ```
   struct queue* tmp = malloc(sizeof(*tmp));
   ```
3. in `dequeue`, you are allocating two buffers of `struct RCB` while imediately lose the reference to them by assign to the pointers `tmp1 and tmp1`, those are not necessary, and you are creating memory leaks. What you need are just two pointers:

   ```
   struct RCB* dequeue(struct queue* queue) {
           struct RCB *tmp1; 
           struct RCB *tmp2; 
           if(queue->front == NULL && queue->back == NULL) {
               printf("queue is empty\n"); 
           }   
           tmp1 = queue->front; 
           tmp2 = tmp1->next; 
           queue->front = tmp2; 
           if(queue->front == NULL) {
               queue->back = queue->front;
                   printf("removed rcb from queue\n");  
           }
           return tmp1; 
   }
   ```